# Import rasters to geoserver - Permission denied

Tags: geoserver

In a Virtualbox, I have Ubuntu server 14.04.2. Installed OpenGeo Suite 4.5 and created a folder inside the geoserver data directory and it was named mydata. In fact it was a copy of the demo folder. I have removed everything inside and loaded the geotif files. the Linux account opengeo is the owner of the mydata folder but still experienced this this permission denied nightmare as showed in figure attached.

What can I try?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to copy here your rasters: /var/lib/opengeo/geoserver/workspaces/opengeo/data
or give 755 permission to your mydata folder and restart the geoserver, but my guess is your data folder should be a subfolder of the geoserver workspaces folder.

Comment: Not sure if that can solve the problem. I put the data where the demo data is so it should be ok. I found that tomcat7 needs to be the owner of the folder and files and have r and w access to the tif files to resolve the permission denied issue. I still have this issue which will be my next task to work on: 
""java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException""

Any clue why this is happening??

Comment: Tried the directory as Tamas suggested. I am still getting this error "java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException".